# Missing argument 1 for method with argument being a service injection in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, oop, doctrine, symfony-3.2

I have such service linked to one method in my entity:

```
entity_form:
    class: AppBundle\Entity\EntityForm
    calls:
         - [setDoctrine, ['@doctrine']]
```

The argument injects (or at least should) **doctrine** into my entity so that I can get stuff from the db inside methods.

I set it for the getter because I had to omit setting the argument in the `__construct` because in code the class is never really *"constructed"*

The entity itself looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="entity_form")
 */
class EntityForm
{

    protected $id;

    protected $url;

    protected $name;

    protected $className;

    protected $description;

    private $doctrine;


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /* _All Getters An Setters Here.._ */

    private function setDoctrine($doctrine)
    {
        return $doctrine;
    }

    public function createEntity($id)
    {
        $this->setDoctrine();

        $entityPath = sprintf('AppBundle:%s:%s', __NAMESPACE__, $this->getClassName());

        var_dump($this->doctrine);
        exit;
        //var_dump is temponary and only for testing the doctrine 

        $entity = $this->doctrine->getRepository($entityPath)->find($id);

        return $entity;
    }
}
```

This entity stores information about forms on the website. With this I would like to nicely and quickly create entity of class for which the form is made, from given Id.

---

### Unfortunately

Running such code gives me this error:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   AppBundle\Entity\EntityForm::setDoctrine(), called in
>   C:\PHP\Repos\centaur\src\AppBundle\Entity\EntityForm.php on line 139
>   and defined

---

What could be the reason for this error to happen? How can I fix it?

Any help would be amazing

Answer (score -1):

> The argument injects (or at least should) doctrine into my entity so
>   that I can get stuff from the db inside methods.

No.

You defined `entity_form` service that is nothing more than `AppBundle\Entity\EntityForm` with setter-injected `doctrine` service.

So your `EntityForm` with injected service is available in container, it won't be injected into every created `EntityForm`.

Looks like you should read more about responsibilities. What you want to achieve in `createEntity` method should be a part of application service layer, not a model itself.

Model is not aware of application/infrastructure concepts, so injecting ORM is not ok.

About mentioned error, considering only service definition and that call:

```
$this->setDoctrine();
```

You want to call setter without required argument, and probably missed that your service definition already did setter-injection.

As I mentioned before, entity is basically not a service, so move that part into specific class and inject database-related service there using standard DI.

Comment: Your answer does not provide any real solutuions.

Comment: @aln447 To a large extent there are no real solutions except to switch from Doctrine to an active record approach.

Comment: I explained you why it is not ok in your approach and shown you possible ways to go. If implementation doesn't work because of design and misunderstandment of how specific technology works, I feel this is a valid way to answer.